# Excel own function: Compile error: Sub or Function not defined

Tags: excel, vba, function

We have a system which exports IP address data always with three digit octets. I am trying to create an own function in Excel in order to remove any unnecessary leading zeros from these IP addresses. I have a proven formula which accomplishes this, but when trying to create a function, I get the Compile error: Sub or Function not defined. 
Any help would be appreciated.

the formula that works:

```
=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE("@." & TRIM(A2), ".0", "."), ".0", "."), "@.", "")
```

e.g. if the cell A2 contains 010.110.009.254 this formula results in 10.110.9.254

```
Public Function IPFix(IP)
IPFix = Substitute(Substitute(Substitute("@." & Trim(IP), ".0", "."), ".0", "."), "@.", "")
End Function
```

I would expect that =IPFix(A2) would result in a valid IP format with no leading zeros.
However I am just getting this compile error.

Answer (score 2):

Replace `Substitute` with `Replace` for the `VBA` function

```
Public Function IPFix(IP)
    IPFix = Replace(Replace(Replace("@." & Trim(IP), ".0", "."), ".0", "."), "@.", "")
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, Tom! This did it. I was working under the (false) assumption that all excel functions would have already been defined.

Answer (score 2):

VBA is *hosted* in Excel, but it's completely distinct: VBA doesn't know anything about Excel's worksheet functions. At least, not natively.

So, `Substitute` isn't defined anywhere - same for `VLookup`, and many other worksheet functions. Some VBA functions have the same name (or a similar one) as Excel worksheet functions, *and behave differently*.

The VBA standard library *does* have a `Strings` module that exposes a number of specialized `String` functions (several of which also exist as worksheet functions, e.g. `=LEFT` vs `Left` and `Left$`).

As [Tom correctly specifies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54331399/1188513), the VBA standard library function that's equivalent to Excel's `Substitute` function, is `Replace` - a function that's defined in the `VBA.Strings` module, which you can explore by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> to bring up the VBE's *Object Browser*:

[image: VBE object browser showing definition for VBA.Strings.Replace]

Since these functions are all globally-scoped, you don't *have* to fully qualify them; that's why & how you can legally write `Debug.Print Replace(string1, string2)`. But know that you could always type `VBA.` and get *IntelliSense* to list what functions are available - `VBA.Strings.Replace` works, as does `VBA.Replace`, or just `Replace`:

```
Public Function IPFix(ByVal IP As String) As String
    IPFix = VBA.Strings.Replace(VBA.Strings.Replace(VBA.Strings.Replace("@." & Trim(IP), ".0", "."), ".0", "."), "@.", "")
End Function
```

Now that's wordy. The benefit though, is that now if your VBA project defines a `Replace` function, places that invoke `VBA.Strings.Replace` or `VBA.Replace`, will still be invoking that function instead of your `VBAProject.Module1.Replace` custom function - because an identifier reference in VBA is always resolved by the compiler, starting with the smallest accessible scope: so a custom function can exist in a custom module and "shadow" or "hide" a VBA standard library function (or any other function defined in any other referenced type library).

Lasty, note that for the times you do need to invoke an actual worksheet function, you can do it from the Excel object model - here using a `With` block to reduce the verbiage:

```
Public Function IPFix(ByVal IP As String) As String
    With Application.WorksheetFunction
        IPFix = .Substitute(.Substitute(.Substitute("@." & Trim(IP), ".0", "."), ".0", "."), "@.", "")
    End With
End Function
```

Worksheet functions invoked like this will work exactly like their actual-worksheet counterparts; you can use `Index`, `Match`, `VLookup`, and *a lot* of other worksheet functions that way, with an early-bound standard VBA member call that will raise a standard VBA runtime error given invalid arguments.

You can also invoke them late-bound, directly against the `Application` object - in which case invalid arguments won't *raise* an error, but *return* one - just like they do in actual worksheets (e.g. `#VALUE!`) - if you want to return that worksheet error value, your function needs to return a `Variant` (implicit like you have, or explicit as follows), because an `Error` is a VBA data type that can't be coerced into a `String` value, so the return assignment would throw a *type mismatch* error:

```
Public Function IPFix(ByVal IP As String) As Variant
    With Application
        IPFix = .Substitute(.Substitute(.Substitute("@." & Trim(IP), ".0", "."), ".0", "."), "@.", "")
    End With
End Function
```

Note that because these calls are *late-bound*, they are only resolved at run-time, which means you must be very careful with typos; you also don't get any *IntelliSense* or "parameter quick-info" to help as you type it.

Comment: Thank you, Mathieu, for the in-depth description and lesson. Much appreciated!